# Stargazer splits character field into columns when summary=F and string contains "&"

Tags: r, stargazer

How can I print a stargazer table when summary=F and a character column has elements containing `&`? `summary=F` prints the data table verbatim which is what I want.

Here's a case where it prints as expected:

```
> stargazer::stargazer(
+   data.frame(ur1=c('hot','tamale'),yum='!')
+   ,type='text',summary=F)

============
   ur1   yum
------------
1  hot    ! 
2 tamale  ! 
------------
```

And here the `&` is split into two columns.

```
> stargazer::stargazer(
+   data.frame(ur1=c('hot & tamale'),yum='!')
+   ,type='text',summary=F)

============
  ur1  yum  
------------
1 hot tamale
------------
```

The same behavior happens in html and latex modes as well. In latex it's easy to hack a fix for a character by commenting out the `&` a la `gsub(x,pattern='&',replacement='\\&',fixed=T)` but that fix doesn't work for html and replacing it with the entity `&amp;` still causes the split. While it would be easy to use `kable` or simple markdown to print the table, I want my this kind of table to have the same style as the stargazer regression tables.

I hope someone can help! Also, I couldn't find a development repo to report it if it's a bug.

I do have the latest version of stargazer:

```
> devtools::session_info()
Session info ------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio (1.1.419)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       Etc/UTC                     
 date     2018-09-14                  

Packages ----------------------
 stargazer     5.2.2      2018-05-30 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very hacky solution, but you could insert a tab (`\t`) and a backspace (`\b`) escape sequence right before the `&`. This seems to work for `type = "text"` and `type = "html"`, but not `type = "latex"`.

```
dat <- data.frame(ur1=c('hot & tamale', 'hot & taco') ,yum='!')
dat[, 1] <- gsub("&", "\t\b&", dat[, 1])

stargazer::stargazer(dat, type = "text", summary=F)
====================
       ur1       yum
--------------------
1 hot & tamale  ! 
2  hot & taco   ! 
--------------------
```

Comment: not really sure and I’m not going to go through the messy source code to find out! My guess is that it encodes to latex and then to text or html and when it encodes to latex it reads & as the new column symbol. The escape characters manage to break that. But since this doesn’t seem to work in latex, it just be something else! FYI check out `huxtable`, which does general tables and regression tables.